# How can i check request comes or not in laravel?

Tags: laravel, request

I want to get `$data['student']` if request get (like: student-guardian?reg_no=0001 in URL).
if no any parameter on url `$data['student']` don't needed.

My `StudentGuardian` function Like:

```
public function studentGuardian(Request $request)
{
    $data = [];
    if(!empty($request)){
        $data['student'] = Student::select('id','reg_no','reg_date', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name','faculty', 'semester','status')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {

                if ($request->has('reg_no')) {
                    $query->where('students.reg_no', 'like', '%'.$request->reg_no.'%');
                    $this->filter_query['students.reg_no'] = $request->reg_no;
                }

            })
            ->get();
    }

    return view(('studentguardian.index'), compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
public function studentGuardian(Request $request)
{
    $data = [];

    // check request has any parameter
    if($request->all()){

        // query and get list student
        $data['student'] = Student::select('id','reg_no','reg_date', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name','faculty', 'semester','status')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
             if ($request->has('reg_no')) {
                 $query->where('students.reg_no', 'like', '%'.$request->reg_no.'%');
                 $this->filter_query['students.reg_no'] = $request->reg_no;
             }
        })
        ->get();

    } else {
        //do something else
    }

    // return data to view
    return view('studentguardian.index', compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `if(!empty($request))` is useless, `$request` is always a `Request` object, not empty.

Second, you can use just `if($request->all()) { ... }` to check if request array is empty.